# Yii multiple user login in an application

Tags: yii

I am a new in Yii framework, I just setup an application and separate **front-end** & **Back-end** part. Both User can register / log in properly. Now I want to login different user from front-end site.
Example : **Front-End** user are tow types

```
                    1. Customer
                    2. Merchant
```

I want to set different role of theme. How to possible it, Please share with me.

Comment: You need to add user verification/ authentication module. This should be preferably outside yii framework. A simple module would have two columns, User and password. Once user logins, verify him from this module and allow access. Later use std user authentication module.

Comment: I didn't see your column details. You have keep record of which user belong to which type/role customer/merchant. Once decided his role assign permission to the user. Use these permission to control his activity on your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to use Yii's RBAC. In order to implement and use RBAC in yii you need to follow the following steps:

1-configure `main.php` which is located at '/path/to/yourApp/protected/config/main.php'

```
'authManager'=>array(
        'class'=>'CDbAuthManager',
        'connectionID'=>'db', //your database config name
 ),
```

2-import yii's rbac database scheme into your database. You can find it under `/path/to/yii/framework/web/auth/` directory

3-add your operations. Operations such as 'VIEW_POST' or 'EDIT_POST':

```
$auth=Yii::app()->authManager;
$auth->createOperation('VIEW_POST','view a post');
$auth->createOperation('EDIT_POST','edit a post');
```

4-create your roles. For example in your case you will have two roles. First `Customer` and second `Merchant`.

```
$role=$auth->createRole('CUSTOMER');
```

5- Assign operations to your roles:

```
$role->addChild('VIEW_POST');
```

6- All done! You can restrict the access like below:

```
if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('VIEW_POST'))
{
//user has access to view a post
}else{
//logged in user has no access to view a post
}
```

You can also check access with role like below:

```
if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('CUSTOMER')) {}
```

In order to assign a role to a user use the `assign` method:

```
$auth->assign('CUSTOMER','USERNAME | USER ID'); //user will hold the CUSTOMER ROLE
```

It might also be noted that, I assumed that you have implemented your authentication class. You can find more about Yii's RBAC and authentication in the following link which is Yii's official document:

[Yii Authentication and Authorization](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth)